# How to apply Bode stabilty criteria to a system with magnitude<0?

Tags: bode-plot

I have a system where the magnitude is less than zero.
I can't determine the stabilty criteria from bode plot, because the magnitude isn't crossing the 0.

The Bode plot is

[image: my system bode plot]

How can I determine the stabilty criteria in this case?

Comment: is that an openloop or closed loop plot?

Comment: Its an open loop

Comment: just checking ;) then it is stable

Comment: What if the magnitude doesnt cut the 0db but the phase did cut the -180 deg. Is it still stable?

Answer (score 1):

The magnitude never crosses zero because the gain is always smaller than 0dB!

Such a system is always stable.

Moreover, the phase margin is always positive, the phase never touches -180deg. Another indication that the system is stable.

Answer (score 0):

So you have an amplifier with an open-loop gain below 0 dB?
This is not an amplifier at all.
Are you sure that it is open-loop?
In this case, it seems to be a **passive** circuit, that never can be unstable.